# What does the ampersand mean in shell script for authentication (curl), and how can I achieve the equivalent in request.post in python?

Tags: python, shell

I have some shell script that is an API that I am trying to convert into Python code:

```
resp=$(curl --silent "${AUTH_URL}" --request POST \
            -H "Host: ${AUTH_HOST}" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-urleed" \
            -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${USERID}&client_secret=${ESCAPED_PASSWORD}")
```

The first part of the `curl` command is straight forward to convert into a dictionary and pass it into `request.post`. But on the last line, after the `-d` how can I write the equivalent in python?

Is it the equivalent of adding the equalities to a dictionary like this:

```
dict(
    grant_type:client_credentials&client_id, 
    client_id:${USERID}, 
    client_secret:${ESCAPED_PASSWORD}
```

Output will be that the API call returns some values and doesn't fall over.

Comment: How about `resp_data = "grant_type="+thisdict['grant_type']+"="+thisdict['client_id']+"&"+"client_secret="+thisdict['client_secret']` and then use the variable `resp_data` to `request.post()`.